# Binding properties of object instances from ObservableCollection to ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, datacontext

I need to bind an `ObservableCollection<T>` property of a view model to a view. This is my view model class.

```
namespace
{
    public class CompositeViewModel
    {
        public CompositeViewModel
        {
            IList<MyType> temp = new List<MyType>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                MyType entry = new MyType();
                entry.Id = 1;
                entry.Name = "Foo";
                temp.Add(entry);
            }

            CollectionB = new ObservableCollection<MyType>(temp);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<MyType> CollectionA
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<MyType> CollectionB
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
    }

    public class MyType
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my XAML user control.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Product.Views.CompositeView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Product.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionB}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <models:CompositeViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
</UserControl>
```

When the application is run, the `ListView` displays the fully-qualified name of the `MyType` class. How do I get it to display the value of the `Id` and `Name` fields instead?

Edit: Added a screenshot of the output I see.

[image]

Edited by ABIN MATHEW to Show my output.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by fully-qualified Name give an example.

Comment: Fully-qualified name of the class means the string `Namespace.MyType`. It's the value you get back by default from the object's `ToString()` method.

Comment: I have tried the exact code you have and i have not viewing any kind of issue. works the way you coded.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your `ListView` showing fully-qualified name.

Comment: Just edited the post.

Comment: i just edited your question to show what i am getting in the listview have a look.

Comment: can you show us how you fill the collectionB ?

Comment: I filled the collection in constructor like this,   `CollectionB = new ObservableCollection<MyType>() { new MyType() { Id = 1, Name = "A" }, new MyType() { Id = 2, Name = "B" } };`

Comment: Done. I've removed all the DAL-related boiler code and brought it down to the basics. The DAL returns an `IList` instance, which is then converted into an `ObservableCollection<T>` instance. This occurs only once when the view model is instantiated.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I'm done with the edit. The code still doesn't work.

Comment: ok where is it broke now ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127837/discussion-between-pranav-n-and-abin-mathew).

Answer (score 0):

I feel stupid now. Turns out I had the following snippet declared in my styles.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It was needed for another `ListView` instance and I had put it in the app resources temporarily. Moving it into the instance's own style definitions fixed the issue.